# HTML copy of php site

Tags: php, html, nginx, copy

I have two servers, server #1 with ip1-public and server#2 with ip2-private. Only I know the IP for server #2, and server #2 will always be private to prevent DDOS attacks.

- server #1 is a simple web host that supports html (and can use twice a day php script with cron)
- server #2 has VDS with php-fpm, nginx.

I want  server #1 to host html files that are created by PHP scripts on server #2(IP2-private).

How is it possible to do this?

For example: server#2 make html files and upload it to pastebin or ftp that don't log ip. Then server#1 download html files from pastebin/ftp. And still nobody knows the ip of server#2.

Comment: Is server#1 HTML only hosting?

Comment: Not only HTML but is it important? Because if it will not be html, it can be vulnerable I think. Html nobody can't ddos a lot because it haven't got big load on server

Comment: Can you use any server side programming language on server#1? If not, you cannot load the content of server#2 without exposing the server address.

Comment: Yes I can use. But again: if it will not be html, it can be vulnerable I think. Html nobody can't ddos a lot because it haven't got big load on server. There can be script that grab html from pastebin for example - so it will not be really important to security

Comment: But there is no way you can use use pure HTML to download the website from another server and then send it to the user. You have to use server side language.

Comment: You can do it using ajax or with an iframe. But both will expose the servers address.

Comment: Ok, I can use php, but only 1 time per day for loading html. How it can be easy to make it?

Comment: >>>But both will expose the servers address. No it can't be anywhere. Ip2 must be private no matter what happens

Comment: If you want it private, put a password on it.

Comment: >>If you want it private, put a password on it.  --->Its not a solution. What more?

Comment: The reasons you have given make no sense. A pure HTML site is no less vulnerable to a DDoS attack, you are misunderstanding how they work. I suggest you do a bit of reading, try some of the solutions above, and come back with a specific issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 2rjdown But it have much less load so its easy to protect - and, it most important, server#2 is working and still haven't problems

Answer (score 0):

In your cron job running on the 'private server', you could:

1. Create the html file for the 'public server'
2. use [scp](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) to send it to a directory of the private server 
   (ex: 
   `scp generated.html user@ip_of_public:/path/to/hosting/directory`

To write html files from PHP you can do the following from within the PHP file:

```
$htmlfile = fopen("afile.html", "w");
$htmltext = "<html><body><h1>Hello from Server 2</h1><p>This is created in server 2</p></body></html>"

fwrite($htmlfile, $htmltext);
```

Comment: How to create html automatically?